# If $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^n)$ is an Artinian $\mathbb{C}$-module, is it a Artinian ring?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I feel I should use the fact that ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^n)$ are equivalent to submodules $\mathbb{C}[x],$ but I cannot see how to use this fact to prove that $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^n)$ is an Artinian ring?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^n)$ is Noetherian so it is Artinian iff primes are maximal.

Comment: @AnHoa Very complicated compared to Qiaochu's straightforward solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the title question is yes: if a $k$-algebra $A$ is Artinian as a $k$-module, then it's Artinian as a ring. The point is that a descending chain of ideals of $A$ is in particular a descending chain of $k$-submodules, so if you know that descending chains of $k$-submodules stabilizes then descending chains of ideals must also stabilize.

In this case all we're saying is that $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^n)$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, and any descending chain of ideals must be a descending chain of subspaces, which must stabilize because its dimension must eventually become constant.